# How can i download a document from firestore into my local computer after it gets updated/created

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, mern

i am creating a website where whenever a document is created i have to download it on my pc and have to process the data.

I am using **onUpdate** cloud function to detect update and then i have to download it, this is the part where i am stucked.

Suppose if **1000 documents** got updated in a single time i have to download all of them on my pc and perform some processing.
And i am not getting it that how can i download them locally after detecting update.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. If you don't know how to read a single document, this explains how to do so: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data If you *do* know how to read a single document, what keeps you from doing that 1,000 times to download all of the documents you want?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes i can read a document i can use onSnapShot but suppose if 1000 documents get added by 1000 users at a single time will onSnapshot queue them or will be able to handle them